# Need to filter records from AUDIT table for a particular column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

PFB the scipts

Step-1(Audit Table)

```
CREATE TABLE AuditTest
(
    ID INT
    ,col1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,col2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,col3 NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,col4 NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,[Action] VARCHAR(10)
    ,[Date] DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE()
)
```

Step-2(Transaction Table)

```
CREATE TABLE Test11
(
    ID INT IDENTITY
    ,col1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,col2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,col3 NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,col4 NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
```

Step-3 (Update Trigger on the transaction Table)

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAudit ON Test11
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO AuditTest(ID
,col1
,col2
,col3
,col4
,[Action]
)
SELECT d.ID,d.col1,d.col2,d.col3,d.col4,'o' FROM DELETED d
INSERT INTO AuditTest(ID
,col1
,col2
,col3
,col4
,[Action]
)
SELECT i.ID,i.col1,i.col2,i.col3,i.col4,'n' FROM INSERTED i
END
```

Step-4 (Insert and update on Transaction table)

```
insert into Test11
select 'a','a','a','a'

UPDATE Test11
SET col1 = 'b'
WHERE ID = 1


UPDATE Test11
SET col2 = 'z'
WHERE ID = 1
```

Need to select all new records(WHERE ACTION = 'N') from the table AuditTest
If any updation made to the column "COL1" Only

Note: Don't want to add any script inside trigger.

Thanks in advance,
Anil

Comment: If you are wiling to add a new field that is an audit sequential identity on the AuditTest table then you can compare to the previous audit record and see if  a particular value in a column has changed.      In this situation I have always done one or both of the following...    changed the trigger code to only make inserts on certain changes, and or , added new action codes such that which columns were updated is buried in the action code.  n1  n2  n3 n4  n24  n14  n0

Answer (score 0):

For each `ID`, This will give you all the updates that were done on `col1` only

```
WITH cte1 AS
 ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY ID ORDER BY DATE ASC, ACTION DESC) RowNum,
          *
   FROM AuditTest 
)
, cte2 AS 
 ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY ID ORDER BY DATE ASC, ACTION DESC) RowNum,
          *
   FROM AuditTest 
)
SELECT cte2.ID, 
       cte2.col1, 
       cte2.col2,
       cte2.col3, 
       cte2.col4,
       cte2.action,
       cte2.date
FROM cte1, cte2
WHERE cte2.RowNum > cte1.RowNum AND 
      cte2.id = cte1.id AND 
      cte2.col1 != cte1.col1 AND 
      cte2.col2=cte1.col2 AND
      cte2.col3=cte1.col3 AND
      cte2.col4=cte1.col4 AND
      cte2.Date = cte1.Date
```

Run these queries one at a time (wait seconds between update statements) to test the solution

```
TRUNCATE TABLE Test11;
TRUNCATE TABLE AuditTest; 
insert into Test11
select 'a','a','a','a'
insert into Test11
SELECT 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'

UPDATE Test11
SET col1 = 'b'
WHERE ID = 1;

UPDATE TEST11
SET col1='c'
WHERE ID = 2;


UPDATE Test11
SET col2 = 'z'
WHERE ID = 1;

UPDATE Test11 
SET col2='z'
WHERE ID=2;

UPDATE Test11 
SET col1='bd'
WHERE ID=2;
```

Results

```
1   b   a   a   a   n   2015-05-19 22:33:15.430
2   c   b   b   b   n   2015-05-19 22:33:20.690
2   bd  z   b   b   n   2015-05-19 22:35:22.427
```